# Add multiple DataFrame series to new series in same DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset in a .csv which I imported into a DataFrame using pandas, organized in the following manner (obviously not real numbers):

```
 A   B   C   D    E    F 
 0  20   4   24   8    28
 1  21   5   25   NA   NA 
 NA  NA  6   26   10   30
 3  23   NA  NA  11   31
```

What I want to achieve is to save the data in two extra columns G and H in the same DataFrame so I get the following:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G   H
                  0   20
                  1   21
                  ...  ...
                  11   31
```

Where I would like to keep the same index for all data (so B belongs to A, D to C, F to E etc.). As you can see, the original dataset has some missing values, so I would also like to skip these if they are in there.

Now, I have looked into [pandas append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) and [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), however I do not see how I can achieve what I wanted, especially with skipping the empty values (presumbly via `data.dropna()` or some other function?).

Comment: How did you perform the operations? Did you create another series to keep the output of the operations?

Comment: @EMT sorry I was unclear on that, the function I use will directly update the existing series, so the current example data table is basically the end result of my function. So my question is: how can I combine column A, C and E and column B, D, F while maintaining the same index for both new colums :)

Comment: @k33da_lets_debug hey, thank you for your comment. The G column should contain the raw values from column A, C, E while the H column should contain the values from the B, D, F columns, with missing values that might occur removed. However, every second column has a value that belongs to the first column (i. e. A 1 & B 21 belong together) and I would like to maintain that index in the new columns G and H, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, your dataframe looks like this:

```
        keywords1   keywords2   keywords3   key1    key2    col2
0       blue        red         green       1       5       NaN
1       big         NaN         medium      2       6       3
2       bat         ball        goal        3       7       0
```

Now lets assume that you need to add first three columns and add to another column. So,

```
col_1 = ['keywords1', 'keywords2', 'keywords3']
df["new_col_1"] = df[col_1].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
```

As I understood that your data contains basically string type data, the above code should work fine. Otherwise, you can convert the columns into string using the`.apply(str)` function.

Older Solution:

You can perform the operation and put it in a `pandas.core.series.Series`. For example:

```
df = pd.read_excel('sample_excel.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') df
```

The output will be:

> ```
>   key1    key2
> 0  1      5
> 1  2      6
> 2  3      7
> ```

Now, let's do some operations:

```
df['key3'] = df['key1'] + df['key1']
df
```

The output is:

> ```
>   key1    key2    key3
> 0  1      5       6
> 1  2      6       8
> 2  3      7       10
> ```

Now save the new dataframe as excel file:

```
df.to_excel('new_sample.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however your operation simply mathematically adds the content of two columns together, while I would like to append the colums into two, larger columns.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by appending two columns.

Do you mean that you want to add the contents from 3 columns and put them in one column? For example if three columns col_1, col_2 and col_3  has values 'a', 'b' and 'c' respectively, do you want another column col_4 with the value 'abc'?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I would like to achieve haha, would you have any clue on how to achieve this? I looked into the append() function of pandas but couldn't seem to figure out a solution that worked :/

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you can share your dataset or at least a portion of it to know the type of data in it and what should be the appropriate function.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Yd9c7Vs.png this is how my dataset looks. I want to append the content of Mol3, Mol6 and Mol10 into a new column "combined_Mol" and Press3, Press6, Press10 into a new column "combined_Press", while skipping the NaN values, and maintaining the same order (MolX and PressX are coupled together) for further analysis and possible plotting, I hope that's clear, I apologize for being unclear.

Comment: I hope the edited answer shall work fine. But you need to be careful about the data type in every column you are adding.

Comment: it wasn't precisely what I was looking for but your answer managed to steer me in the right direction, so thank you!